# Multiple Markers are not rendered in React Leaflet Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

I am using react-leaflet to display multiple markers with specific lat and lng fetched from MongoDB using axios. I can see that my data are correct with console.log. But, when I map the locationData the markers are not appearing.

Here is my code.

```
const LeafletMap = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [locationData, setLocationData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        location.getAll().then(res => {
            setLocationData(res.data);
        })
    });

    return(
        <MapContainer className={classes.mapPane} center={[16.831374910711716, 96.15512062779219]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={true}>
            <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            {
                locationData.map(({_id, name, location, type}) => {
                    <Marker position={[location.lat, location.long]} key={_id}> 
                    </Marker>
                })
            }

        </MapContainer>
    )
}
```

Here is my sample data fetched from my database.

```
{
    "name": "University of Sheffield",
    "location": {
        "lat": 53.38208784924988,
        "long": -1.4888865317372872,
        "city": "Sheffield"
    },
    "type": "University"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `return`. Following code works for me:

```js
locationData.map((data) => {
        return (
          <Marker position={[data.lat, data.lng]}>
            <Tooltip><b>{data.location}</b></Tooltip>
          </Marker>
        )
})
```